# Managing layouts in Backbone.js / SVG web app?

Tags: javascript, layout, svg, backbone.js

I am building a Backbone.js app which makes use of a number of SVG elements.

The image below shows the basic setup - a variable number of "widgets" that should fill up most of the screen.

Each widget view is a Backbone view that (when it has setup its own DIV container with an SVG:SVG element) instantiates subviews with SVG:G elements.

**I have a 2 questions:**
*1) What would be a good way of controlling the external layout?*
I.e. the user should be able to add and remove widgets (divs) that flows horizontally and this should be reflected in the URL state. (With each corresponding WidgetModel serialized).

*2) What would be a good way of controlling the internal layout?*
I.e. when the browser window is resized, how do the inner SVG subviews get their widths/heights.
The approach I took to this before was having a (window).resize handler that could find out the widget sizes and pass the layout via the model to all views and subviews:

```
$(window).resize(function() {               
    var activeWidgets = [widgetModel1, widgetModel2 ...]
    each activeWidgets
         widgetModel.set({width: widgetWidth, height: widgetHeight})
});
```

But perhaps that is an unnecessary hack? Another approach would be each WidgetView having its own resize handler but then I have to pass around the width/height to the sub-views that need explicit values?

[image]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand fully what you want to do. What happens when the window resizes? Do all the widgets change their dimensions? How?

Another question is: do the width and height belong in the model? Would you save that together with the widget? Or is it just for display (and you can calculate it depending on the window size?)

If they are just for display, keep it in the views. Have a WidgetsView that manages all the WidgetView views, and then the window resizes calculates the layout and tells each WidgetView to resize itself to (width, height). Then I suppose that each WidgetView knows how big its inner views should be, so each WidgetView should resize what's inside it accordingly.